# ASP.NET VNext Class Library System.Runtime.Serialization

Tags: asp.net, serialization, datacontractserializer, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

Trying to make a serializable class in ASP.NET vNext Class Library Project. Not able to give my class items [DataContract] or [DataMember] Attributes. As I just started exploring vNext so I am little confused. If some one can guide me whether I am doing the right thing or not. My little sample code.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Schlouds.Business.Entities
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Student
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Guid StudentId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use the DataContractSerializer you need to mark your types with the required attributes.  You state you cannot (you don't give a reason why) and you show code that does.  It isn't clear what the issue is here.

Comment: The code sample I pasted here have errors on attribute tags (DataContract and DataMember). The swirly lines of IDE wont appear hear in stack's editor. The problem I am facing in this code is that even after using namespace for serialization, VS is not able to identify both attributes and thus giving me compile time error.

Comment: You can also grab this package from nuget package store in side VS2015. Just search 'System.Runtime.Serialization' and it should find it and allow you to add it to a specific project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you have to add "**System.Runtime.Serialization**" to the "**frameworkAssemblies**". 
See example project.json file:

```
"net45": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Reflection": "4.0.10-beta-22416",
            "System.Reflection.Extensions": "4.0.0-beta-22526",
            "System.Reflection.Primitives": "4.0.0-beta-22526",
            "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.0.0-beta-22526",
            "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22526",
            "System.Collections.Specialized": "4.0.0-beta-22526",
            "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22526",
            "System.Linq.Expressions": "4.0.0-beta-22526",
            "System.Linq.Queryable": "4.0.0-beta-22526",
            "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22526",
            "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.0.0-beta-22526",
            "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml": "4.0.10-beta-22526",
            "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json": "4.0.0.0-beta-22526"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, but is a shame since it means that it's just pointing to an assembly in the GAC rather than a package. http://stackoverflow.com/q/30747965/299327

Answer (score 3):

This is the unofficial API to match the old namespace to the new ones.

http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/

for those attributes you need System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml 4.0.10-beta-22416 if you using core

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json** (or **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml**) package from Nuget for .net core.