# How to get CPU load in .NET Core (dnxcore50)?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I porting my web-app to .NET Core (dnxcore50) and some features is dropped.
I know about crossplatform features of .NET Core and i want to know how i use old  System.Management performance counters for get CPU, RAM, Network load ?

Maybe now need write platform-dependent utils for pushing data to my abstract monitoring service written with .NET Core?

Comment: I'll Keep in mind @CodeCaster

Comment: I think it doesn't always mean that when you put some words between {} it is code,To emphasize on some of the technical terms we can use it.

Comment: @ZOXEXIVO you can just [reference framework assemblies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747965/what-is-the-difference-between-dependencies-and-frameworkassemblies-in-proje).

Comment: they should be used for code (and code-like artifacts). @CodeCaster

Comment: Ohk @CodeCaster thanks :)

Comment: @CodeCaster, i want use pure .NET Core on system without .NET Framework

Comment: Well there's no Windows Management Instrumentation in .NET Core.