# Asp.net Core RC2 not detecting Reference to nuget package

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2, project.json

Im using Clean RC2 Template for web application.

after adding Reference to System.linq it gives me this :

[image]

Im using 461 as framework.

Comment: Did you restore packages after modifying your project.json?

Comment: @svick yes ive done that. if i remove those like projects workds well.I guess JC1001 answer is corret. so when i set 461 , i dont need to add reference inside package.json , since its using desktop dotnet framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's automatically restore back the package version to match the targeted framework version (net461).
So actually it's "detecting" nuget packages.
You trying to target 461 in the image, so the packages rolling back from .net core preview1 to .net framework 4.6.1 .
If you want target multiple framework (or as I see you want RC2 packages, meaning want .net core), your `config.json` file's frameworks section should look like this for example:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net461": { // old .net framework
      "dependencies":{
        "System.LINQ": "4.0.0.0"
      }
   },
   "netstandard1.5":{ // .net core
       "dependencies":{
        "System.LINQ": "4.1.0-RC2-*"
      }
   }
},
```

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) is a good info about targeting platforms

If you just want use .net core, remove the net461.

I see you want ASP.net core. [Here](https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples/blob/master/HelloMvc/project.json) is some cli ASP MVC samples.
[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore) is a really nice ASP.net core sample project (using latest .net core, you have to update to RTM/preview2)

Answer (score 1):

You should already be able to use LINQ in your code (using System.Linq) without having to add a reference.

Since you are targeting .NET 461, you can add any additional GAC references in the frameworkAssemblies section in your project.json, e.g.

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.ServiceProcess": "4.0.0.0",
            "System.Configuration": "4.0.0.0"
        }
    }
},
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747965/what-is-the-difference-between-dependencies-and-frameworkassemblies-in-proje) for an explanation between dependencies and frameworkassemblies.